# Delete (not backspace) on Android keyboard

Tags: android

I can't find delete button on android keyboard (not backspace). How to proceed delete action? Should I setup something?

Comment: There isn't one native on android.

Answer (score 11):

AOSP, Google and OEM keyboards don't implement a <kbd>delete</kbd> key so you need other software. [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) is a 3rd party virtual keyboard that tries to offer a full pc keyboard experience so it has a <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

P.S : other 3rd party keyboards might have the same option, I just gave one example and am not affiliated with that software in any way.

Comment: Never type passwords with a 3rd party keyboard. You never know...

Answer (score 3):

There is a <kbd>backspace</kbd> key in all the keyboards by default , but I don't think it is a rule for <kbd>delete</kbd>.

Many custom keyboards like *Swiftkey*, *Flesky*, etc have options to directly erase one word or the entire thing.... but they don't have <kbd>delete</kbd> as well.

You may try to use this ["Hacker's keyboard"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en), but it's still not visible on the screen, and you need to switch to additional view to get the button. To me it is almost the, in terms of actions needed, as to tap on the text, where you need to delete, and then to press the <kbd>backspace</kbd> button.

This cannot be done in any default android keyboard, unless manufacturer put it there from the very beginning.

---

UPDATE: I intentionally checked different phones/tablets of my friends and around office, and discovered that some Android tablets have this button, standalone. It works out of the box, they have it in both portrait and horizontal orientations of the screen. For example Samsung Galaxy Tab:[image]